# Meteor.js - Can not find module

Tags: javascript, meteor

I can't seem to be able to make Meteor.js find my custom module. I've tried all kind of pathings but it just doesn't seem to find it at all!

**server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';

import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import AppContainer from '/client/AppContainer.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup

  const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

  export const renderRoutes = () => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/test" component={AppContainer}/>
        <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
});
```

**client/AppContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Blaze from 'meteor/gadicc:blaze-react-component';

import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './test.html';
```

Any clue why it's behaving like this when the file clearly exists?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Which module is not seen and logs, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Trying moving your server/main.js file in to client/main.js

Your Router file should  be declared on the client, and I suspect this is what is causing the issue!

Comment: This answer will work, but it's important to note *why* it works. Meteor will refuse to import anything in a `server` folder to the client, and vise-versa. It's a helpful protection mechanism to protect server-only code from being leaked to the client